# GitHub - Hiding the Public Activity/My Actions

Tags: github

I have a free account on GitHub. I have noted that there is not any obvious way to switch off or to control the 'Public Activity'. Therefore, every time I commit or do something even trivial it shows up in my Actions and is available as an RSS feed.

Is there a way to control or to switch off the public activity option?

Comment: Apr. 2022: this is now supported! See my [edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8057244/6309).

Answer (score 33):

Sept 2022: confirmed:

> ### [Private profiles are now generally available](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-29-private-profiles-are-now-generally-available) (Sep. 2022)
>
> Private profiles (now generally available) enables users to turn their GitHub profile "private", which gives users control over features that share user data across the GitHub platform.
> When a profile is private, the following content is hidden from the profile page:
>
> - Achievements and highlights
> - Activity overview and activity feed
> - Contribution graph
> - Follower and following counts
> - Follow and Sponsor buttons
> - Organization memberships
> - Stars, projects, packages, and sponsoring tabs
>
> To enable this setting, visit https://github.com/settings/profile.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/8809849/163482779-f1330384-78a0-4497-b9df-18641929de0b.png?w=847&ssl=1 -- image]
>
> Learn more about [private profiles](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/setting-your-profile-to-private).
> As we continue to release new privacy control features, please share your [feedback](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/categories/profile-feedback).

---

Update Apr. 2022, eleven years later: Yes!

> ### [Private Profiles](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-04-21-private-profiles/)
>
> Users now have the ability to turn their GitHub profile “private”, which gives users controls over features that share user data across the GitHub platform.
>
> To enable this setting, visit https://github.com/settings/profile.
>
> [image: https://github.blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/image-2-1.png]
>
> Private profiles are in public beta.

---

2011: I don't think there is a way to customize what your public activity shows. The social coding network that GitHub represents is founded on that very same "public" activity. The only way to restrict it is by [*paying* for private repositories](https://github.com/pricing).

---

Note: since 2011, [GitHub was acquired by Microsoft](https://news.microsoft.com/announcement/microsoft-acquires-github/) (June 2018), and the current (2021) pricing include unlimited private repositories(!)

So using private repositories is a good option, considering you can now easily [change a repository's visibility](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/setting-repository-visibility#changing-a-repositorys-visibility).

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/repository/repo-change-select.png]