# How to delete Repositories contributed to on github?

Tags: github

I forked a project, pulled and pushed. My `github` account is showing this:

[image]

Is there a way to remove that from my profile?

I already deleted the repositories from my settings page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As I was saying 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8057244/6309), your public activity is... public.

In this instance, you made a pull request which was accepted by the original repo you forked: that will remain part of your public record (even if your activity in the forked repo itself is gone, since you have deleted said fork).