# How do I remove my "repository contributed to" for a specific Github repo?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally made a pull request or raised an issue for RxJava. I don't know which one, but one of these activities caused my Github page to display that repository as one of my contributions. How do I remove it from the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub - Hiding the Public Activity/My Actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055684/github-hiding-the-public-activity-my-actions)

Comment: @poetryrocksalot I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

click your profile photo --> Settings --> Repositories --> choose Repos you need to leave

Answer (score 1):

By some another answers here in SO, there is not way to do this.

[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26346168/1771682)

[Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8057244/1771682)

Basically, they say you cannot hide your public activity. And contributions are public activities.

---

But here are some important infos about Contibutors:

**What counts as a contribution**

On your profile page, certain actions count as contributions:

- Committing to a repository's default branch or gh-pages branch.
- Opening an issue.
- Proposing a pull request.

Contributions only count if they were made within the past year.

More info in [Viewing contributions on your profile page](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile-page/)

Comment: This doesn't remove that listing on your page, that you contributed to a project.

Comment: It's pretty weird, I made an issue with a project halfheartedly thinking maybe the developer would find it interesting, and now it features prominently above all my accomplishments on github for all time.  Couldn't find a way to cancel the creation of the ticket.