# Is it possible to hide certain activity from my GitHub profile?

Tags: git, github, commit, history

Lately I've been contributing to a project from a public organization in GitHub. For personal reasons, I've decided that I don't want such commits or anything related to the organization to be displayed in my GitHub profile anymore.

Is there any way I can modify such commits from the past, like overwriting them in a certain way, so they don't appear in my profile?

Thank you very much. Best regards.

Comment: Note: a private account (now supported since Apr. 2022) could help! See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52452526/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2018: You would need to [change the author information of your local commits](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/) (using another account name), and then `push --force` back to the origin/upstream repo.

That `push --force` is not always possible, and you will have to contact the owner of the organization for them to replace the history of one branch by another, and make sure everybody reset his/her own local repo accordingly.

But the point remains: you cannot hide "some" of your activities.

---

Apr. 2022: unless... you:

- use a different account for that organization,
- set that second [account as private](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8057244/6309), which will hide any activity.